# fullcalendar jquery display month plus 1

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using a customized version of fullCalendar. I would like my initial display and page reloads to display the following month. So the current month is March, when I bring up the calendar I would like to see April as the default month. I see this block of code.

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
var options = {
    weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "short",
    day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"
};
```

I tried to change the third line
var m = date.getMonth();
to
var m = (date.getMonth()+ 1);

This had no affect. I am out of my element here. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the date immediately when the calendar loads, then you can use the `defaultDate` option within your calendar setup options. Since fullCalendar uses momentJS, you can also use momentJS to really easily, dynamically select the current month +1, e.g.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: moment().add(1, 'month')
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/306/ for a working demo.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/defaultDate and http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/ for more details

Answer (score 1):

if you are using fullcalendar >= v5, use `initialDate`

example :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'month',
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  initialDate: '2020-01-02'
});
```